# Pegar um arquivo em rede em java

Tags: java, arquivo

Eu consegui abrir um arquivo e colocá-lo em um Jlabel na máquina onde estou desenvolvendo. Mas quando eu coloco a aplicação na rede a máquina que está na rede, ela não localiza o arquivo. É possível pegar o arquivo de uma máquina em rede?
O meu código está da seguinte forma e funciona perfeitamente na minha máquina que estou desenvolvendo.

```
String figura = jtResultadoPesquisa.getValueAt(jtResultadoPesquisa.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString(); // quardo o nome do arquivo na figura

String caminho = new File("/home/Pictures/").getCanonicalPath(); // pego o diretorio onde esta o arquivo

ResultadoCaminhoFigura = caminho +"/"+ figura; // tenho o caminho com a figura

ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon (ResultadoCaminhoFigura); //crio uma instancia e coloco a figura e diretorio onde ela se localiza
img.setImage(img.getImage().getScaledInstance(300, 430, 100));

jlVisualisarimagem.setIcon(img); // e seto a figura em um jlabel para ser visualizada.
jlVisualisarimagem.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
jspVisualizarimagem.getViewport().add(jlVisualisarimagem);
```

Eu coloquei os comentários só para facilitar o entendimento. Quando rodo em minha máquina funciona legal, mas quando eu coloco a aplicação em rede ela não traz a imagem. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Abraços a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Apesar da sua pergunta estar ampla, você não deve estar conseguindo acessar a figura porque esse caminho é local (próprio do seu computador):

```
String caminho = new File("/home/Pictures/").getCanonicalPath();
```

Quando você roda o programa em outras máquinas, elas buscam no próprio diretório delas, e não no seu computador (lugar onde a imagem necessária está). Uma maneira delas acessarem o seu computador para buscar a imagem é através do IP. Por exemplo:

```
String caminho = new File("172.168.1.50/home/Pictures/").getCanonicalPath();
```

Onde 172.168.1.50 é o endereço IP do seu computador. Claro que você irá precisar das permissões necessárias de acesso para a leitura da imagem, entre outras configurações.
Lembrando que este é só um exemplo de acesso para computadores em rede.

Comment: G Zullian, além de fazer isso que você colocou eu tive que compartilhar a pasta que se encontra no servidor. Como o servidor é fedora eu instalei o samba, compartilhei a pasta e utilizei o endereço ip que você descreveu para localizar a pasta compartilhada no servidor. Valeu. muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Exatamente, quando falei das permissões e outras configurações era disso que se tratava. Que bom que conseguiu, peço que aceite a resposta para ajudar outros usuários. Abraço!